# Generic query for any DB

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, wildcard

I've created a query available for the Oracle and Access DB.
The query is a simple `select` experssion includes wild cards.

```
string query = @"SELECT t_package.Package_ID FROM t_package   
                WHERE t_package.PackageFlags   
                LIKE '#WC#VCCFG=#WC#CheckedOutTo=#WC#'";  

//set the wild card according to the DBMS type that current repository based on.
  string wildCardCharacter = "";
  wildCardCharacter = RepositoryType().Contains("Access") == true? "*" : "%";

//Replace wild card characters with the appropriate one.
  query = query.Replace("#WC#", wildCardCharacter);
```

I would like the query to be suitable also for the following databases:

•
MS SQL Server
•
MySQL
•
Oracle9i
and 10g
•
PostgreSQL
•
MSDE
•
Adaptive Server Anywhere
•
Progress OpenEdge

Any ideas how to set the appropriate wild cards for each?

Comment: You forgot to mention what your programming language is, but I suppose it'll have associative arrays, dictionaries or a similar data structure. That'd be my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik only Access is not using Standard SQL ***** and **_** as LIKE wildcards (I'm not shure about Progess OpenEdge)